# Voronoi diagram with a specified number of sites and vertices

Tags: algorithm, vertices, voronoi

I want to draw a Voronoi diagram with 9 sites and with
1. no vertex
2. 1 vertices
3. 4 vertices
4. 7 vertices.

How do I approach this question. The one with no vertex is easy, it can be done by collinear points.
What about the others.

A figure for each would be appreciated.

Comment: This is offtopic but try points on a circle for 1 vertex.

Answer (score 0):

Simple examples are:

- 4 vertices: Tic-tac-toe configuration,
- 7 vertices: configuration of sites on 3 rays going from same
  point equidistantly positioned. Vertices are ray origin point and 3 times by 2
  vertices between rays.